# Resolver lifetime when mapping with a custom value resolver

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I am using `AutoMapper` v9.0.0, I have source and destination objects which both contain a one to many parent/child relationship.

When the map is invoked, a sequence of ~100k `SrcParent` objects with < 100 `SrcChild` objects are processed. Each parent map is invoked individually so an existing instance of a `DstParent` object can be seeded with a `DstParent.ConfigurationId` value, the `MyValueResolver` value resolver can only perform the `SrcChild` to `DstChild` conversion with this data.

The mapper is added to the asp.net core di container with the lifetime overridden using `services.AddAutoMapper(assemblies, ServiceLifetime.Singleton);`.

However, the mapping configuration instantiates a new resolver for each child regardless of the specified lifetime. What other options exist to efficiently convert a collection of parents where each child instance in the children sequence needs a hint that is only available at runtime on the destination parent?

```
public class SrcParent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<SrcChild> SrcChildren { get; set; }
}

public class SrcChild
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SrcParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class DstParent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ConfigurationId { get; set; }
    public List<DstChild> DstChildren { get; set; }
}

public class DstChild
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DstParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

this.CreateMap<SrcParent, DstParent>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dst => dst.ConfigurationId, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dst => dst.DstChildren, opt => opt.MapFrom<MyValueResolver>());

public class MyValueResolver : IValueResolver<SrcParent, DstParent, List<DstChild>>
{
    public List<DstChild> Resolve(SrcParent source, DstParent destination, List<DstChild> destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        /*
         * Many expensive operations that can be safely cached
         * on the resolver instance through the lifetime.
         */
    }
}

// Seed the mapper with an existing instance to hint the child conversion.
var dst = new DstParent
{
    ConfigurationId = 42
};

this.mapper.Map(src, dst);
```

Comment: There is a MapFrom overload that takes a singleton resolver instance as parameter.

Comment: But if you need to cache stuff during a Map call, you need context.Items.

Comment: I see now that `opt.MapFrom(new MyValueResolver())` scopes the instance as a singleton. The downside is I that loose ctor injection from the service provider, however I can get that from the context's provider. Please add a quick answer for me to select.

Comment: Perhaps a cleaner way would be to simply extract that logic in a singleton service and inject that in the transient resolver service.

Comment: That's a good idea, I already encountered undesirable side effects due to the inability to share the instance across profiles. Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a MapFrom overload that takes a singleton resolver instance as parameter.
Perhaps a cleaner way would be to simply extract that logic in a singleton service and inject that in the transient resolver service.